# update query on temporary table issue - mysql

Tags: mysql, temp

update query does not update the values into temporary table in mysql.

```
DECLARE _defaultDateTime DATETIME;
DECLARE _resourceTypeId CHAR(36);
DECLARE _billedUsageHrs DECIMAL(15,6);
DECLARE _unbilledusageHrs DECIMAL(15,6);
DECLARE _billedCost DECIMAL(15,6);
DECLARE _unBilledCost DECIMAL(15,6);
DECLARE _resourceIdentifier CHAR(36);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _usageTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _usageTable(resourceinstanceId CHAR(36),billedusageinHrs DECIMAL(15,6), billedusageCost DECIMAL(15,6),                       unBilledusageinHrs DECIMAL(15,6), unbilledusageCost DECIMAL(15,6)) ENGINE=MEMORY;


UPDATE  _usageTable SET resourceinstanceId = 'a17b5e49-000c-11e3-8bfa-842b2bac06e5' WHERE 1 = 1;  

SELECT resourceinstanceId, billedusageinHrs, billedusageCost, unBilledusageinHrs, unbilledusageCost FROM _usageTable;
```

The above stored procedure returns empty row

Comment: is there any autocommit set to false?

Comment: Are we missing an INSERT Statement somewhere?

Comment: Well, when there's no data in the table, there's nothing to update. Simple as that.

Comment: no. but when i tried insert the values to temp table it works. update doesnt.

Comment: Explain that. And show the whole procedure. How do you think we can help you without necessary info?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _usageTable(resourceinstanceId CHAR(36),
                                   billedusageinHrs DECIMAL(15,6), 
                                   billedusageCost DECIMAL(15,6),
                                   unBilledusageinHrs DECIMAL(15,6), 
                                   unbilledusageCost DECIMAL(15,6)) ENGINE=MEMORY;


UPDATE  _usageTable SET resourceinstanceId = 'a17b5e49-000c-11e3-8bfa-842b2bac06e5' WHERE 1 = 1;
```

`UPDATE` will update *existing* rows.

*As far as I can see*, you just created the table. So it is empty. There is simply *no* row to update.

Perhaps are you looking for [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) instead of [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) ? Or maybe you example does not put emphasis on the *real* problem?